# Struts 2 display tag

Tags: displaytag

While retrieving huge words in a single column using  tab, the entire form get corrupted and the fields inside the form are not working. But with small data in the same form it is working perfectly.

Can someone tell me what's happening?

Comment: update your question by adding example source code of your work would help you out to get some solutions.

Comment: There's nothing here anyone can use to help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.